# How to free my data from a Node.js Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I've worked with Java Script APIs for a while now but this is the first time I've tried to sample from an active stream which will never emit `'done'`. My goal is to get a set number of samples from the stream per hour. The stream is connecting and streaming a lot of information, but I have not been able to get the returned data into a format where I can do further processing on it (like I'm familiar with in a data science workflow).

It feels like I've been staring at the docs for days now, and noticed most straightforward examples pipe the readable stream into a file on the server. This seems inefficient for my application. (To have to write it to a file, only to read it in again to do more processing on it before then sending it to the browser for rendering through the fetch API or sending it to the project's mongoDB for long term storage and deep analysis. I'm pretty sure there is a way to set the JSON as a `const` or `var` and I'm just not familiar with it.

How do I get my data into the `saved` Java Script variable? What do I need to change or add to my code to be able to keep manipulating and processing the returned JSON?

```
const needle = require('needle');

const token = process.env.BEARER_TOKEN;
const streamURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/sample/stream';

function streamConnect() {
    const options = {
        timeout: 2000,
    };

    const stream = needle.get(
        streamURL,
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        },
        options
    );

    stream
        .on('data', (data) => {
            try {
                const json = JSON.parse(data);
                // console.log(json);
            } catch (e) {
                // Keep alive signal received. Do nothing.
            }
        })
        .on('error', (error) => {
            if (error.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
                stream.emit('timeout');
            }
        });

    return stream;
}

function getTweetSample() {
    const s = streamConnect();
    const chunks = [];
    s.on('readable', () => {
        let chunk;
        while (null !== (chunk = s.read())) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        }
    });
    setInterval(() => {
        s.destroy();
    }, 3000);
    return chunks;
}

const saved = API.getTweetSample();
console.log('saved: ', saved);

// Above returns
// "saved: []"

// Expecting 
// "saved:
{
{
  data: {
    id: '1301578967443337***',
    text: 'See bones too so sure your weight perfect!'
  }
}
{
  data: {
    id: '1301578980001230***
    text: 'Vcs perderam a Dona Maria, ela percebeu q precisa trabalhar e crescer na vida, percebeu q paga 40% de imposto no consumo enquanto políticos q dizem lutar por ela, estão usufruindo dos direitos q ela nunca vai ter  Trabalho escravo é ter q trabalhar pra vcs'
  }
}
...... // 20 examples
}"
```

Edited 2020-09-07

This is a sample of the payload of the response:

```
PassThrough {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: true,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: false,
    ....
}
```

Comment: Does this correctly summarize your issue: 1) Connect to a remote JSON API. 2) Download/stream data from the API and stream parse the response 3) gracefully terminate the stream after receiving 20 samples?

Comment: Yup i'd say that accurate, with the additional 4th step that the data is returned to a const or var for further processing.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example payload of the data returned by the API? The structure of the JSON data is important to determine how the data stream must be parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three steps to tackle the challenge:

1. The data must be fetched as a streamed HTTP response body
2. The response stream must be parsed by a JSON parser as data is streamed from the response
3. The stream shall terminate after 20 elements have been parsed by the JSON parser

The example code from the OP already illustrates how to solve (1).

There's a selection of libraries out there to parse a stream of JSON data on-the-fly to solve (2). My personal preference is `stream-json` since it only requires a single line of code in our pipeline.

Finally, (3) will require the code to terminate the incoming stream before it completes. This will cause nodejs to throw a `ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE` error, which can be handled by a targeted catch statement.

Combining these steps will become something like the following executable POC. I don't have a Twitter API token, but I think this will work:

```js
const stream = require('stream');
const util = require('util');
const got = require('got');
const StreamValues = require("stream-json/streamers/StreamValues.js");

(async () => {
  const token = "<YOUR API TOKEN>";

  const dataStream = got.stream('https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/sample/stream', {
    headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` },
  });

  // This array will by filled by JSON parsed objects from the HTTP response
  const dataPoints = [];
    
  await util.promisify(stream.pipeline)(
    // This readable stream [dataStream] will emit the incoming HTTP body as string data
    dataStream,
    // The string data is then JSON parsed on the fly by [stream-json]
    StreamValues.withParser(),
    // Finally, we iterate over the the JSON objects and push them to the [dataPoints] array.
    async function(source){
      for await (const parsedObject of source){
        dataPoints.push( parsedObject.value );

        if( dataPoints.length === 20 ){
          // When we reach 20 data points, the stream is forcefully terminated
          dataStream.destroy();
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  )
    // Prematurely terminating the stream will cause nodejs to emit a [ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE] 
    // error. If it is OK to return more than 20 elements, you could try to remove the 
    // [return] statement on L28;
    .catch(error => (error.code !== "ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE" && Promise.reject(error)));
}())
  .catch(console.error);
```